# Do you use keyboard to design?

Tags: design, keyboard

I was checking Openlabs NekoEX5 on the net and I really loved it. So, I was wondering do you use keyboard when you do sound design, if so which one? Is it in occasional situations? I use my library and the computer for editorial( Pro Tools). Is it hard to shift from one system to the other?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I recently started turning to my Axiom and Digi's Structure and NI's Absynth to do some design work. As it's all in the same box, the shift is more a mental one than a gear-based one.

Answer (score 1):

I use a keyboard (the Kork nano-key! I traded my big Novation for this tyke and don't regret it!) for synth stuff and sometimes Max/MSP control. But not often.

Comment: I love my Nano Key. It's great for when you need a keyboard occasionally and don't have space for things like one on top of a ProControl or Icon.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to messing with different tones, I use my keyboard when I fire up Absynth 5. But usually I step record a lot of the MIDI data with my trust lil mouse.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for basic midi keyboard and structure - its all ready to go and great for getting quick design ideas together.

Answer (score 0):

I can't go wrong with Ableton Sampler and an SL 49.
Especially for morphing/flying/growing sounds it's great to twist knobs.
Designing Sound has some great Jim Stout videos.